# Ubuntu - Unable to ping windows computers

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, vnc, ping

I have a very strange problem.

I am unable to ping windows PCs on my local network, whereas they are able to ping my ubuntu laptop.

Another thing is I can actually VNC onto one of the PCs but cant to ping it.
Only thing I am able to ping on the local network is localhost and the router.

Has anyone got any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: The Windows computers might be treating the network as 'Public', or 'Network discovery' might be turned off. See if changing the network to 'Home' / 'Work' and turning on 'Network discovery' helps.

Comment: Do you try to ping with name or with ip address?

Answer (score 2):

You have firewall installed on windows machine which is configured to block ICMP packets.

Comment: Hi, the windows machines only have antivirus and no software firewall. Wierd thing is, if I boot from my backtrack 5 live CD I can actually ping these devices :S

Comment: @Sidi0u5 Maybe its the windows standard firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, windows firewall may be blocking the icmpv4, you could turn on file and printer share in the windows firewall
run>firewall.cpl >allow an app or feature through windows firewall>file and printer share

If this not worked add the firewall rule by running the following command using an admin command window.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ping" protocol=ICMPV4 dir=in action=allow
```